# Solve $\sin(5A) + \cos(5A)\sin(A) - \cos(3A) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do you solve this equation for A:
$~~\sin(5A) + \cos(5A)\sin(A) - \cos(3A) = 0$

I've tried expanding it many times, but I can't seem to be able to reduce it to a format I can work with. Is there a simpler method of solution than repeated expansion?

Comment: Sketching the graph of the function suggests it has 10 real roots in $[0,2\pi)$ and is then periodic with period $2\pi$.  Unless you enjoy solving order-10 polynomials, you may be restricted to numerical methods.

Comment: Multiplying out the brackets gives sin(6A)+2sin(5A)-sin(4A)-2cos(3A)=0. I don't know if that helps or not.

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$ \sin(5A) + \cos(5A) \sin(A) - \sin(3A) = 0 $$
Let $ x = e^{iA} $ and use De Moivre's,
$$ \frac{x^5 - x^{-5}}{2i} + \frac{x^5 + x^{-5}}{2} \frac{x - x^{-1}}{2i} - \frac{x^3-x^{-3}}{2i} = 0 $$
Multiply by $ 4i x^6 $,
$$ 2(x^{11} - x) + (x^{10} + 1)(x^2 - 1) - 2(x^9 - x^3) =  $$
$$ (x^2 - 1)(x^{10} + 2x^9 + 2x + 1) = 0 $$
The phase of each root to the polynomial above (the ones with $ | x | = 1 $ at least) is a solution $ A $ to your equation (up to an integer addition of $ 2\pi $).

Answer (score 1):

Try using $\cos{A} = \sin\frac{\pi}{2}-A$ and the $\sin{A} + \sin{B}$ or $\cos{A} + \cos{B}$ formulas. You can also write $2 \cos{A}\sin{B} = \sin(A+B) - \sin(A-B)$, which actually will reduce $\cos{5A}\cdot\sin(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20sin%285A%29%20%2b%20cos%285A%29sin%28A%29%20-%20cos%283A%29%20=%200) gives an explicit $12^{\text{th}}$ order polynomial and finds ten real roots.